# CTAN - All tags allowed

Tags: ctan

I have received the following clear message, but would like some advice on the process of uploading a package to `CTAN`.

```
...
Response from CTAN:
[["WARNING","License not found","GPLv3"],
 ["WARNING","Topic not found","doc"],
 ["WARNING","Topic not found","dev"],
 ["INFO","Upload succeeded"]]
```

Is there an official list of the tags allowed (licences, topics...) ?

Comment: This is more or less a question to the CTAN team not TeX.SX. IMHO for new packages it is enough to use https://www.ctan.org/upload and click to "show explanations" and "show all fields". The `l3build` manual also documents several "tags" in the `uploadconfig` table.

Comment: @cabohah Indeed: we got the list by asking CTAN about their API ...

Comment: @JosephWright Is it normal that I can't see my package on CTAN even though the upload was successful? I imagine there is a delay, but in this case how long is it?

Comment: @projetmbc The packages are processed manually. Until someone from the ctan team processes the upload, it should show in https://ctan.org/incoming Once it is processed you should get a mail by a friendly ctan team member.

Comment: Aside: If GPLv3 refers to the GNU Public License, I urge you to use a different license, unless you understand GPL and understand its consequences. For something at CTAN, the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL, now v1.3) is usually more appropriate. Some folks profer the simplet MIT license, or SIL OFL if the work is a font. My observation, not particular to CTAN, is that many programmers attach GPL only because they see others do it, not because they know what it means.

Comment: @rallg What is the problem with GPL? Is it because it forces users of this library to license their own software based on it with the same license?

Comment: That's part of the problem. It means that if you think you will become famous because your code is used by X Y and Z, you are out of luck: Upon seeing the GPL, X Y and Z will not use your code, and ignore you. There are other burdens, which are especially annoying to end-users who do not need much. But it's your code; do what you want.

Comment: @rallg I will study that for LaTeX package even if they will not become famous... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to find tags.

1. For subjects, there's https://ctan.org/topics/highscore, but it's not very easy to use.
2. For licences, there is https://ctan.org/license: choose a licence and the tag will be accessible in the URL of the licence text.